# SQLDependency subscription not registered and Query Notification message has Source Statement and Info Set Options

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, service-broker, sqldependency, query-notifications

I am developing an application with SQL Dependency feature.
When i execute the application, subscription was not registered.
and `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` has no entry.
i used SQL profiler to trace the issue and i noticed that subscription was not registered as i did not receive message `1 – Subscription registered` but instead got `3 – subscription fired` with the following Notification message:

```
<qnev:QNEvent xmlns:qnev="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotificationProfiler"><qnev:EventText>subscription fired</qnev:EventText><qnev:SubscriptionID>0</qnev:SubscriptionID><qnev:NotificationMsg>&lt;qn:QueryNotification xmlns:qn="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification" id="0" type="subscribe" source="statement" info="set options" database_id="0" sid="0x01"&gt;&lt;qn:Message&gt;2c231f39-60c7-4a73-b575-617a791930f3;d06f0979-8f9b-490e-90ca-6042ab38d68c&lt;/qn:Message&gt;&lt;/qn:QueryNotification&gt;</qnev:NotificationMsg><qnev:BrokerDlg>2FAE7196-0E30-E411-8F82-0050569E473E</qnev:BrokerDlg></qnev:QNEvent>
```

and when i checked it has following information:

```
Type: Subscription, Source: Statement and Info: set options
```

and when i checked msdn for the meaning it says `The connection options were not set appropriately when the command was submitted.`

this is the connection string i am using

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=crmserver;Initial Catalog=crmdatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword" />
```

and following is the code i am using:

```
  public List<Customer> GetLeadUpdates(SqlDependency dependency)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = "SELECT id, name, salary FROM [dbo].[CustomerTest]";
             connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {                  
                command.Notification = null;
                dependency.AddCommandDependency(command);
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();                
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                var list = new List<Customer>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var customer = new Customer();
                    customer.Id = (int) reader["id"];
                    customer.Name = reader["name"].ToString();
                    customer.Salary = (int) reader["salary"];
                    list.Add(customer);
                }
                return list.OrderBy(p=>p.Id).ToList();
            }  
        }
    }
```

please let me know what i have to do to register the subscription successfully. i have service broker enabled and using "sa" credential in the connection string to connect to db so i suppose i dont need any specific permission to subscribe for notification as sa is the dbo of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the connection SET options reported in Profiler to verify the following SET options are effective:

```
ANSI_NULLS ON
ANSI_PADDING ON
ANSI_WARNINGS ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
ARITHABORT ON
```

Note that `ARITHABORT` must be set `ON` explicitly after the connection if the database compatibility is set to 80 (SQL Server 2000).

Comment: I executed DBCC Useroptions on SSMS and resultset shows that everything you mentioned are already turned on: 'textsize 2147483647',
'language us_english',
'dateformat mdy',
'datefirst 7',
'lock_timeout -1',
'quoted_identifier SET',
'arithabort SET',
'ansi_null_dflt_on SET',
'ansi_warnings SET',
'ansi_padding SET',
'ansi_nulls SET',
'concat_null_yields_null SET',
'isolation level read committed'

Comment: Can you try Profiler instead of SSMS?

Comment: what events i have to trace in profiler to get this resultsets?

Comment: Audit login and ExistingConnection will include the SET options.

Comment: After checking in profiler, every options are set as you mentioned except ArithAbort which is off.

Comment: Then your database is probably in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode.  You will need to either explicitly issue a SET ARITHABORT ON or change the compatibility to a later one.  I suggest you change the compatibility unless you have a specific reason not to.  It may just be the setting is an artifact of an upgrade long ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60311/discussion-between-alagesan-palani-and-dan-guzman-sql-server-mvp).

Comment: Much thanks Dan! Modifying database to COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100 made my day!